# Ajax image upload failure, Script doesn't get the php isset function

Tags: php, ajax

I've been following along with some ajax uploading tutorial and it was working properly.

Here it's how i done,
i created a form in html like this.

```html
 <form id="submit_form" action="php-script/test_lates_statusbx-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                     <div class="form-group">  
                          <label>Select Image</label>  
                          <input type="file" name="ui-is-status_is_photo_fl" id="image_file" />  
                          <textarea name="status_is_text_ara"></textarea>
                          <span class="help-block">Allowed File Type - jpg, jpeg, png, gif</span>  
                     </div>  
                     <input type="submit" name="is_status_forum_btn" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload" />  
                </form>  
<div id="image_preview">  
            </div>
```

and here its my ajax code,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit_form').on('submit', function(e){  
           e.preventDefault();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"php-script/test_lates_statusbx-script.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:new FormData(this),  
                contentType:false,  
                //cache:false,  
                processData:false,  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     $('#image_preview').html(data);  
                     $('#image_file').val('');  
                }  
           })  
      });  
      
 });
```

and my php looks like this,

```
if(isset($_POST['is_status_forum_btn'])){
    echo $fileactuname = basename($_FILES['ui-is-status_is_photo_fl']['name']);
    echo $textareastatus = htmlspecialchars($_POST['status_is_text_ara']);
}
```

**Problem**: When i click the submit buttons it doesnt execute my code. But if i echo something outside of the isset function will does.Where am i wrong ?

Comment: in your php script before `if` condition put `print_r($_POST);` and check what parameters you're getting in `POST` variable and the desired parameter you're checking in `isset` is available or not

Comment: @Haridarshan Im not getting any if i echo it inside the isset function

Comment: why you're doing `echo` inside `isset` condition.  Print `$_POST` outside `isset` condition and show what output you're getting

Comment: @Haridarshan my entire website file uploading doesn't  working with jquery now. Do you have any solutions ?

Comment: Since you are sending the form data yourself via your client-side script, the submit button value will not be part of what is submitted - so your check for whether the submit button value was send fails.

Comment: I found the answer, Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submit button is only a successful control if it is used to submit the form.

You are:

1. Using the submit button to submit the form
2. Preventing the default behaviour of the submit event so the form is not submitted
3. Collecting the data from the form with JavaScript
4. Making an HTTP request with that data

Since (due to step 2) the submit button is no longer being used to submit the form, it isn't included in the object you create with `FormData()`.

Test for the presence of a different piece of data that you *are* sending.

e.g.

```
if(isset($_FILES['ui-is-status_is_photo_fl']))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php script, try like this

```
if  (
    isset($_FILES['ui-is-status_is_photo_fl']['name']) && 
    $_FILES['ui-is-status_is_photo_fl']['error'] == 0
) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($_POST);
    // Do the required task here
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: I found the answer, Thank you anyway !